# How to make background color animate on scroll from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code

```html
      <div class="titlediv" style='background:linear-gradient(90deg, #cc2900 79%, #b3b3b3 21%);'>
        <h2> Hii
        </div>
        
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        <p> My name is Josh and I need Help </p>
        
      <div class="titlediv" style='background:linear-gradient(90deg, #cc2900 79%, #b3b3b3 21%);'>
        <h2> Hii
        </div>
```

As you can see, there are 2 `<h2>` tags with background colors.

I want to make the background color fill from left to right when it appears on screen.

Just like this website: http://html.wwwebinvader.com/MovieMe/MovieMe-Light/index.html

Scroll down and see IMDB rating etc..

Comment: I tried few things @Paulie_D, i did not knew, i had to include them in the question. Give me 5 minutes, i will include them. Thanks

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Tracking elements inside the current viewport

Basically, you need to listen to the [`scroll` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) on the `window` and check whether your heading elements (`h2`) are inside the viewport or not, using [`.offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) and [`offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight).

#### Animating CSS gradients

Regarding the gradient animation, [`linear-gradient` are not animatable](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/linear-gradient/).

The solution is to have the initial gradient as the `background` of the element, and then stack another gradient on top of that one using another element (or [`pseudo-element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)), with the proper `z-index` values and then use other animatable properties to fake the gradient animation.

Usually, you will be using `opacity` to transition from one gradient to another (first example) or `position`, `left`, `top`, `width`... to fill in gradients progressively (second example).

#### Example transition between two gradients

```js
// Get all the heading elements:

const titles = document.querySelectorAll('.title');
const total = titles.length;

let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

// Track the current heading, as you don't need to recheck those that have already been shown once:

let current = 0;

function onScroll() {
  // Get the bottom scroll position:
  
  const bottomScrollY = window.scrollY + windowHeight;
  
  // Check each heading that has not been shown yet:
  
  for (let i = current; i < total; ++i) {
    const title = titles[i];
    
    // Check that the heading is completely visible (all of it inside the current viewport):
    
    if (bottomScrollY > title.offsetTop + title.offsetHeight) {  
      // Add it the .active class:
      
      title.classList.add('active');
      
      // Skip this heading the next time:
      
      ++current;
      
      // If all headings are already active, remove the listeners:
  
      if (current === total) {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
        window.removeEventListener('resize', onResize);
      }
    }
  }
}

function onResize() {
  // Update windowHeight:
  
  windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
}

// Initialize for the first time:

onScroll();

// Start listening for scroll and resize events:

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #000;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #F00 0%, #FF0 100%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00F 0%, #0FF 100%);
  transition: opacity ease-in .25s;
}

.active::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">TITLE 1</h2>

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>

<h2 class="title">TITLE 2</h2>

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>

<h2 class="title">TITLE 3</h2>

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>

<h2 class="title">TITLE 4</h2>

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
        
<h2 class="title">TITLE 5</h2>

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
```

#### Example filling in gradients progressively

```js
// Get all the heading elements:

const titles = document.querySelectorAll('.title');
const total = titles.length;

let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

// Track the current heading, as you don't need to recheck those that have already been shown once:

let current = 0;

function onScroll() {
  // Get the bottom scroll position:
  
  const bottomScrollY = window.scrollY + windowHeight;
  
  // Check each heading that has not been shown yet:
  
  for (let i = current; i < total; ++i) {
    const title = titles[i];
    
    // Check that the heading is completely visible (all of it inside the current viewport):
    
    if (bottomScrollY > title.offsetTop + title.offsetHeight) {  
      // Add it the .active class:
      
      title.classList.add('active');
      
      // Skip this heading the next time:
      
      ++current;
      
      // If all headings are already active, remove the listeners:
  
      if (current === total) {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
        window.removeEventListener('resize', onResize);
      }
    }
  }
}

function onResize() {
  // Update windowHeight:
  
  windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
}

// Initialize for the first time:

onScroll();

// Start listening for scroll and resize events:

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity ease-in .25s;
}

.title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF0 0%, #FFF 100%);
  transition: width ease-in .25s;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.active::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">TITLE 1</h2>

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>

<h2 class="title">TITLE 2</h2>

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>

<h2 class="title">TITLE 3</h2>

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>

<h2 class="title">TITLE 4</h2>

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
        
<h2 class="title">TITLE 5</h2>

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but it is not doing what i wanted. 

I want the red color to come from left to right on scroll.

Comment: @JoshPoor I'm not sure exactly what's the desired visual effect you want to achieve, but I added an explanation and example on how gradients are _animated_. You should be able to adapt that to your needs.

Comment: See the link, which i provided to see what i want. But thanks a lot for the explaination

Comment: @JoshPoor The second example may be closer to what you need.

Comment: Yeah, it is 100% closer, But i do not want that. I want the red color to come from left.  See this page http://html.wwwebinvader.com/MovieMe/MovieMe-Light/index.html
and scroll down.

I cannot find anything like that on the web, i read around 50 blogs

Comment: @JoshPoor Starting from the code in the second example, you should be able to style the `::before` `pseudo-element` to look like bars. If you need a more complex shape, you could use normal elements (e.g.: `<span>`), which can contain others inside. Then, if you need each bar to have a different `width`, you can use different classes. If you get stuck on something, feel free to open another question showing us what you tried so far and what your new issue is, so that your question doesn't get downvoted again and maybe even closed.